# Import database , mysql triggers not running

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm importing an sql file into a database.

The sql file is a export of an old database with some new users added in after.

When i import it , all the users are imported , but the trigger that adds the users to other tables doesn't run .

Edit : It works if i import a blank database and then insert the names after.

snippet of sql file (User table with trigger) :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `overall_user_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `overall_score_workshop` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `studentid`, `team_id`) VALUES 
(1,'User Name',1111,1); // this goes on for 127 names


--
-- Triggers `users`
--
CREATE TRIGGER `Insert Into Classes` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO `ppm2`(`user_id`) VALUES (new.id);
INSERT INTO `pca`(`user_id`) VALUES (new.id);
INSERT INTO `pth1`(`user_id`) VALUES (new.id);
INSERT INTO `pth2`(`user_id`) VALUES (new.id);
INSERT INTO `pds2`(`user_id`) VALUES (new.id);

INSERT INTO `userbadges`(`user_id`, `badge_id`, `seen`) VALUES 
(new.id,1,0),
(new.id,2,0),
(new.id,3,0),
(new.id,4,0),
(new.id,5,0),
(new.id,6,0);

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements in your script gets executed in the sequence of their appearance.

For the trigger to fire, you have to execute the `INSERT` statements on `users` post creation of the trigger.

Change part of your script file as below:

```
--
-- Triggers `users`
--
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Insert_Into_Classes` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 -- write trigger body here
 END;
//
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `name`, `studentid`, `team_id`) VALUES 
(1,'User Name',1111,1); // this goes on for 127 names
```

It is True that script files are auto generated by `dump` tools.
And the generated files does not contain the SQL statements in the same order as most of us expect.

Alternatively,

1. You can take dump of databases *without* data but with all other
   database objects like Triggers, Functions and Procedures.
2. And, take DATA statements as an explicit dump.
3. Execute the above dumps in the same order.
4. You can now check that the Triggers fire as expected.